# Detect Boolean toggle of @Published property with Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have the following published property on my view model in Swift:

```
@Published var myBool = false
```

I would like to have a trigger that fires only when `myBool` toggles.

How would I do that using Combine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a subscription to your published property but you need to make sure you droop the first value to make sure it is only triggered for when the value toggles.

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
@Published var myBool = false

// ...

init() {
    $myBool
        .dropFirst()
        .sink { newValue in
            print(newValue)
        }
        .store(in: & cancellables)
}
```

Comment: I actually went ahead and did that because I noticed the behavior you described. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `@Published` property is also a publisher in terms of Combine, just `sink` it

```
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

$myBool.sink { value in
    print(value)
}
.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: I think, you should add that we need to "remove duplicates", so that we run the action `print(value)` only when the value changes and not when the value has been set in the data source.

Comment: interesting. I'll do that. Thanks